# Crafter CMS 3.0 File Upload Limit

Tags: crafter-cms

How can I set file upload limit for specific content type in crafter 3.0. Say for example Content type ABC must have file upload limit of 25MB where as Content type XYZ Must have file upload limit of 10MB.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own Data Source that imposes the desired limits.

Here is how to build your own DS: https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/developers/extending-studio/build-a-data-source.html